# On dispatch() I get an empty array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I try to learn `react` and `redux` and I got stuck. I looked to other examples online but they are very complicated. My example is very basic and simple. I need to understand what is happening here first.

In **index.js** I dispatch an action, `addJoke`, but in console I don't see anything, but an empty array.

The code is [here on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n0177pxr34) so will be easier for everyone to see it, modify it and test it.

Please someone tell me where I made a mistake.

Comment: Add this in index.js ```store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
})```

Answer (score 0):

changes in Reducer file  : action.jokes in place of action.joke

```js
const jokesReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_JOKE":
      return [...state, action.jokes];

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default jokesReducer;
```

Comment: I changed that my friend by I still get an empty array. You can check yourself in sandbox.

Comment: you dispach a action on startup of your application so after every change it will reflect . means go to sandbox and open AddJokes .js file  . and type anything between div tag on line 4 .  after each change your app reflect new action state